# When can you replace the generators of a group with conjugates?

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I am under the (perhaps false) impression that it is sometimes possible to replace a generator of a (non-abelian) group with its conjugate, and have the new generators generate the same group.

For which groups is this true?

Comment: I just learned this morning that something like the property you suggest is called “invariable generation”. Here’s [a paper on invariable generation by Charles Cox](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04748).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $S = \{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$ is a generating set for a group $G$,  then $\{g^{-1}x_1g,\dotsc,g^{-1}x_ng\}$ is a generating set for all $g \in G$. This latter generating set is  the image of $S$ under the inner automorphism  $h  \mapsto g^{-1}hg$. However, one cannot in general replace  the $x_i$ by conjugates by *different* elements of $G$.

Assuming you know about free groups, consider $G$  a free group of rank 2 generated by $a$ and $b$. Then $\{a,baba^{-1}b^{-1}\}$ is *not* a generating set for $G$. It turns out that if  $\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$ are a free basis for $F_n$  a free group of rank $n$, it's a mildly delicate question for which $g_i$ the set $\{g_1^{-1}x_1g_1,\dotsc,g_n^{-1}x_ng_n\}$ is another free basis for $F_n$. (The answer is called *Whitehead's algorithm.*)

Here's an obvious sufficient condition that can be practical to check by hand but difficult to use in the abstract. Suppose $S = \{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$  is a generating set for $G$, and that $g \in \langle x_2,\dotsc,x_n\rangle$. Then $\{g^{-1}x_1g,x_2,\dotsc,x_n\}$ is again a generating set for $G$.